# Regex to match multitple conditions in sentence

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to match `${xyz}` in a sentence. I tried this expression `\$\{[^\s]+\}` it worked for me. But I have more scenario like the  matching word(${xyz}) should not have space in it and it should not be like this `${xyz` and `$xyz}` and `${xy z}` .

**Accept**

- Hi ${xyz}, Thanks for your visit.

**Not accept**

- Hi ${xy z}, Thanks for your visit.
- Hi ${xyz }, Thanks for your visit.
- Hi ${xyz, Thanks for your visit.
- Hi $xyz}, Thanks for your visit.
- Hi {xyz}, Thanks for your visit.

Note : It should match the entire sentence.

Comment: post the inputs where your regex fails.. try this, `\$\{[^\s{}]+\}`

Comment: Your conditions are already matched with the given regex. Check on www.regex101.com

Comment: It should match the entire sentence. But it is matching only the word

Comment: Oh. So does that mean you want to match all sentences with the string "${xyz}".

Comment: @SendhilkumarAlalasundaram yes

Comment: Can you update the question too, because it is not self-explanatory that you want to match the entire sentence

Comment: question updated @SendhilkumarAlalasundaram

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128603/discussion-between-sendhilkumar-alalasundaram-and-sharan-de-silva).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[\s]*([^.!?]*\$\{[^\s]+\}[^.!?]*[.!?])
```

A group match of the above regex will give you the sentence, without any leading space characters.

I have matched a sentence by checking for strings that end with characters ".","!" or "?".

You can check the meaning of the regex [here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Its match nothing. can you check

Comment: How are you checking?

Comment: it's working but if I give like  "Hi ${xyz}, Thanks for your visit Hi ${xy z},Thanks for your visit Hi ${xyz }, Thanks for your visit Hi ${xyz, Thanks for your visit Hi $xyz}, Thanks for your visit Hi {xyz}, Thanks for your visit"   It matches everything.

Comment: Because you did not complete the sentence with the characters mentioned in the answer

Comment: If a single sentence has both ${xyz}(valid) and ${xy z}(invalid) It accepts.